# Problem syncing user profile information to Site Collection

Tags: 2010, user-profile, user-profile-service, synchronisation

SharePoint 2010 Server - I've got a Site Collection where the user profiles aren't getting updated from the farm profile store. Especially I noticed that photos I've uploaded to the user profiles are not displayed in the site collection.  Other site collections are syncing properly.

I tried the steps I have done in 2007 (deleting the old sync db entries) but no luck.

Any ideas on resolving this in SharePoint 2010?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this? If yes, can you post the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe recreation of User Profile Sync would solve the issue.

**To start copy youe settigs**:

1. AD connection settings
2. connection filters, DBC
3. preffered search center
4. Mysite host (and personal path)
5. Audiencies (all other added manualy)
6. Profile, Social and Sync DB names (to give the same name while recreating)

**Delete UPS and Sync DB**:

1. CA->Manage secive Applications ->User Profile Service Application -> delete (DO NOT check "delete data association)
2. MS SQL there 3 related dbs:

   Profile DB - stores user info ad activity

   Social DB - stores tags and notes

   Sync DB - staging between AD and SP while it syncing

Delete only **Sync DB** (check "close existing connections)

**Recreate UPS application**:

1. CA ->Manage Serice Application -> create new UPS Application
2. Enter DB names, my site host and path (everything the same as was before deletion)
3. Highlight created UPS Application and click "Administrators", add search crawler account with permission to "Retrieve People data for Search crawlers"
4. Recreate connections and other settings
5. Start full sync